# How do I pass the select_tag's input to the rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to insert the input from a select_tag to my controller method.
I've looked and cannot seem to resolve the issue.

This is the code I have below, nothing for the rank's selection comes up in the params at all.

```
<h1>hello please set <%= @user.username %>'s rank'</h1>

  <%= select_tag 'rank', options_for_select(@ranks.collect{ |r| [r.rank_name] }) %>
  <%= button_to "Update", :action => "set_user_rank_update", value: "#{@user.id}", method: :post %>
```

Update below with the controller and routes

Controller:

```
class Admin::RankController < ApplicationController
  before_action :admin?
  def new
    @rank = Rank.new
  end

  def create
    @rank = Rank.new(rank_params)

    if params["rank"]["admin"].to_i == 1
      @rank.toggle! :admin?
    end

    if @rank.save
      flash[:success] = "Rank created"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Failed to create rank"
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def set_user_rank_new
    @user = User.find_by_id(params["format"])
    @ranks = Rank.all

  end

  def set_user_rank_update
    @user = User.find_by_id(params["value"])
    @rank = Rank.find_by_id(params["rank"])
    @rank_backup = @user.rank.first
debugger
    @user.rank - @user.rank.first
    @user.rank << @rank

    if @user.rank.first == @rank
      flash[:success] = "Set user's rank"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Failed to set user's rank"
      @user.rank - @user.rank.first
      @user.rank << @rank_backup

      render 'set_user_rank_new'
    end
  end

private
def rank_params
  params.require(:rank).permit(:rank_name, :rank_color)
end
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,
              :controllers => { :registrations => "member/registrations" , :sessions => "member/sessions"}

    scope module: 'public' do
      root 'welcome#index'
    end

    scope module: 'member' do
      get 'members/:id'           => 'member#show'
    end

    scope module: 'admin' do
      get 'rank/new'         => 'rank#new'
      post 'rank/create'     => 'rank#create'
      get 'rank/set_user_rank/new'     => 'rank#set_user_rank_new'
      post 'rank/set_user_rank/update'     => 'rank#set_user_rank_update'
    end

end
```

Comment: could you please add your controller? so I can see how are you checking the params

Answer (score 1):

Try passing 2 element arrays to options_for_select.  The way you have it looks like it would get you option text but no values, which could explain why it doesn't show up in the params.

So for example:

  `<%= select_tag 'rank', options_for_select(@ranks.collect{ |r|[r.rank_name, r.id] }) %>`

Answer (score 1):

The `button_to` helper creates an inline form with just the parameters included in the helper statement (in this case the user id).

You can check this by examining the resulting HTML on your page - which I think will show an input field for rank sitting outside the form tag.

To include the rank parameter, you should set up the form using a form helper and make sure the rank input is included inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

For what purpose do you need it in your controller action? 
With the link_to you can forwards params as well. 
It would be very helpful to see your controller and also your routes.